# Gremlin on IDE without java code (like the shell)

Tags: eclipse, groovy, graph-databases, gremlin

What is the relation between gremlin and groovy? I put groovy on eclipse and it works but...I guess gremlin is a bit different..(can't write on eclipse editor and run, the way I do on the gremlin shell)..for example, writing 5 + 4 and running as a "groovy shell" configuration in eclipse doesn't do the job..How to go about this?

Edit : What I'm looking forward to doing is create a social graph(with data inside) from about half a million tweets that I have and then run queries on it. I tried neo4j but the browser has a limit to the size of DB I guess. Any neo4j IDE (with cypher as well as graph visualization)??
Then I find gremlin which is amazingly easy and straightforward but then again no IDE to run on!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a great answer but perhaps it will put you on the path to solving your problem. Gremlin uses a variation of the Groovy Shell, so perhaps it does not quite work in the same manner as the Groovy Shell plugin to Eclipse.  You can evaluate Gremlin in the standard Groovy Shell if you follow these instructions:

https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Using-Gremlin-through-Groovy#use-from-groovy-shell

As a follow-on to your edit - In my view, the Gremlin Shell is about all you need to load and analyze graph data.  Consider this blog post:

http://thinkaurelius.com/2013/02/04/polyglot-persistence-and-query-with-gremlin/

Gremlin is still there for you once you get past ad-hoc analysis.  Build your applications over the graph with it.  Here's another post:

http://thinkaurelius.com/2013/07/25/developing-a-domain-specific-language-in-gremlin/

One think [TinkerPop](http://tinkerpop.com) does not have is a built-in visualization function.  [Rexster's](https://github.com/tinkerpop/rexster) [Dog House](https://github.com/tinkerpop/rexster/wiki/The-Dog-House) has such a feature but it's not terribly advanced especially as compared to Neo4j's console.  The typically workflow for visualization that I recommend if using TinkerPop and Gremlin is to dump your graph or a portion of it to GraphML or GML, and then import into tools like [Gephi](https://gephi.org/) or [Cytoscape](http://www.cytoscape.org/) for visualization needs.

Comment: Thanks! 
I didn't really explain the problem well at first..my fault!